# Why do I need to use array destructuring in function to re-render the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In function setBit I use array destructuring and bits are updated and component is re-rendered

```
function App() {
  const [bits, setBit] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

  const changeBit = index => {

    setBit(prevState => {
      prevState[index] = 1;

      return ([...prevState])
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log(bits));

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="app">
        <ul>
          {bits.map((bit, index) => {
            return <li onClick={() => changeBit(index)}>{bit}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when I return prevState without array destructuring like that

```
  const changeBit = index => {

    setBit(prevState => {
      prevState[index] = 1;

      return (prevState);
    });
  };
```

the bits are updated, but the component doesn't re-reder.

What is the difference between prevState and [...prevState]?

[Here is the link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bits-c7c8r)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are returning the same object (to React) to update the state (i.e., prevState) - you have mutated the object - this won't cause a re-render. If you destructure the array [...prevState] this is a new object and causes the re-render.

Comment: Your answer explains everything. Do you think there is a better solution to udpate this array or is it ok like I did?

Comment: It seems as succinct as you can make it. If I were code reviewing it, I'd be happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript

```
let stringA = ‘some string’
let stringB = ‘some string’
```

`stringA === stringB` will returns `true`, because both stringA and stringB have same value and refer to the same primitive.

**BUT** this is not the same with **Objects**

```
let stringA = new String(‘abc’)
let stringB = new String(‘abc’)
```

Now `stringA === stringB` will return `false`, because although the values are equal, two different objects are created in memory, so they both refer to two different objects, so this comparison has failed in reference comparison.

in your case `prevState` is not equal to `[...prevState]` as it create a new object in memory and as per React functionality it treat this a new state which later cause re-rendering of the component